# SwiftUI prevent @NSManaged property from being @Published

Tags: swiftui, core-data, property-wrapper-published

The prerequisite to my question is the following: I have an `@NSManaged` object and I wish to observe and manipulate it. However, I do not want to receive all updates. To illustrate why – suppose it has properties `selectedIndex` and `currentArray`. Those are `@NSManaged` and they are all I need to store and recreate `currentItem`.

There are two ways I could do this. The wrong one would be to use `currentArray[currentIndex]` in my views. **Wrong** because should the update get triggered when I set index and before I change array – I can easily get out of bounds exception. Same if I change array first.

The second approach would be to restrict direct access to these properties from other classes and instead provide an interface to interact with it which would also take care of the internal logic. For example `goToNextItem()`, `changeArrayTo()`, etc.

And along this route the easiest approach would be to mark `selectedIndex` and `currentArray` as private. And, one would assume, this would also prevent other views from receiving updates when they change.

The problem – it doesn't.

Here is a super simple example:

```
final class DataModel:ObservableObject {
    @Published private var internalCounter = 0
    var externalCounter = 0
    
    func incInternalCount() {
        externalCounter += 1
        internalCounter += 1
    }
}

struct Playground: View {
    @ObservedObject var dataModel = DataModel()
    var body: some View {
        Text("Refresh count \(dataModel.externalCounter)")
        Button {
            dataModel.incInternalCount()
        } label: {
            Text("Increment")
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

As you can see, even though I am not able to access `internalCounter` from my `Playground` AND that changes to `externalCounter` are not published – I still receive updates whenever `internalCounter` changes.

This doesn't necessarily create an issue for me – as long as my publicly facing interface has a solid logic, nothing will crash. However, I kind of don't like this idea of having `body` recalculations in response to properties changes, when I **explicitly** made those properties unavailable for access :)

Hence my question – is there a way to make `@NSManaged` property not `@Published`? :)

**UPDATE**

I see that my simplified example is causing some confusion, so let me outline a slightly more elaborate one:

```
final class DataModel:ObservableObject {
    @Published private var itemIndex:Int = 0
    @Published private var items:[String] = ["hello", "world"]
    @Published var currentItem:String
    
    var operationsCount = 0
    
    init() {
        currentItem = ""
        currentItem = items[itemIndex]
    }
    
    func goToNextItem() {
        operationsCount += 1
        itemIndex += 1
        currentItem = items[itemIndex] //Comment this to see problem
    }
    
    func goToPreviousItem() {
        operationsCount += 1
        itemIndex -= 1
        currentItem = items[itemIndex] //AND this
    }
    
    func nextItemAvailable() -> Bool {
        return itemIndex < items.count - 1
    }
    
    func previousItemAvailable() -> Bool {
        return itemIndex > 0
    }
}

struct Playground: View {
    @ObservedObject var dataModel = DataModel()
    var body: some View {
        Text("Item: \(dataModel.currentItem) \(dataModel.operationsCount)")
        HStack {
            Button {
                dataModel.goToPreviousItem()
            } label: {
                Text("Previous")
            }
            .disabled(!dataModel.previousItemAvailable())
            Button {
                dataModel.goToNextItem()
            } label: {
                Text("Next")
            }
            .disabled(!dataModel.nextItemAvailable())
        }
        
    }
}
```

`items` and `itemIndex` is what I need to persist my data. However to display it, I need `currentItem` and next/previous functionality.

If you comment out the lines indicated - updates will happen. And although they are not a problem given that nothing will crash – would be nice to avoid them for the benefits of performance :)

Comment: Note on your example code.
 AFAIK, your `Playground` view is refreshed, not because `externalCounter` is updated,
 but because you update `internalCounter` in your `func incInternalCount()`.
 Comment out `internalCounter += 1` and you get the desired behaviour. Note, it is best to use `@StateObject var dataModel = DataModel()`. To **not** refresh the view when `internalCounter` is changed, try using the
 new `@Observable`, see: [Managing model](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app), it is supposed to cater for this.

Answer (score 0):

The data model object should only store the array of data, not any info about selection, that should be stored in the `View` struct hierarchy using `@State` and then `@Binding` for write access, make funcs for logic, computed properties to transform data. If you think about it, what if you wanted to allow selection of the same data in 2 screens? That wouldn't be possible if the selection is within the data model.

> I kind of don't like this idea of having body recalculations in
> response to properties changes, when I explicitly made those
> properties unavailable for access

That's why the first step in designing a `View` is ask yourself what data does it need to do its job? In your case it doesn't need the whole model object, only write access to the property so it should be:

```
struct Playground: View {
    @Binding var counter: Int
    var body: some View {
        Text("Refresh count \(counter)")
        Button {
            counter += 1
        } label: {
            Text("Increment")
        }
    }
}
```

If you want a side effect when setting the counter, in a model struct you can use `didSet` or in an ObservableObject configure a Combine pipeline in init, starting with `$counter` and ending with `.assign`. Usually objects are only used when you need reference type semantics, ie async (Not async/await though, because we have `.task`'s internal convenience object for that).

Comment: I updated my answer to illustrate my issue better

Comment: Its best to use the View structs instead of objects for this because they already have changed detection built-in. Combine's ObservableObject isn't designed for what you are trying to do. Break up your Playground into multiple Views, use let for read access and @Binding for read/write. The data model object should only store the array of data, not any info about selection.

Comment: How would it help if DataMofel is NSManagedObject? That is really my issue.

Comment: With `NSManagedObject`s from `@FetchRequest` you usually are working with objectIDs not indicies.

Comment: Maybe the name DataModel is confusing. In the real app, I have Question entities. And I have a Test entity. Test is generated and contains questions. Test may be of different type, it has a set of Questions attached to it and also some arrays such as correctQuestions, etc. this lets me easily back up my data and restore it. I know this can be done differently and converted to state storage etc. However, my question is not about that, but about how to prevent NSManaged property from causing state updates. IMHO it’s not great that private properties are causing state updates

Comment: So I think its best to have the `@ObservedObject` in one `View` then pass off each property to its own sub-View. That way although the View's body is always called it won't always be called in each sub-View, only when its value has changed. We call this tighter invalidation by the way. Initing a View struct is as lightweight as initing an int so don't worry about it.

Comment: So using my last example - imagine that Next and Previous buttons are in a separate tab view. How do I allow them to increment the index, without monitoring the whole DataModel? Can I make them listen to and be able to manipulate individual properties of an ObservedObject?

Comment: You can use a binding to a published property in an ObservedObject but that is usually only when you need to do something async, otherwise there is no point in the object, and usually it is just a binding to a state var or a state struct will do.